# How to use erase module of fabric.js in rect+ts?

Tags: typescript, fabricjs, rect

How to use erase module  of fabric.js in rect+ts? I want to use the easing module of fabric.js in rect+ts. How should I import it? Or what to do? Since the erasing module of fabric.js does not support ts, what should we do?